# Give a type of another defined schema to an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I try to define an array 'comments" with a type Comment(another schema).

```
    const beerSchema = new Schema({
    name:String,
    country:String,
    color:String,
    alcoholPercent:Number,
    upvotes:{type:Number,  default:0},
    comments:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'comments'

    }]

});
```

collection object

```
 [
    {
        "upvotes": 0,
        "comments": [],
        "test": [],
        "_id": "5b0092af2cdf6b30b80dd386",
        "name": "newName",
        "country": "Belgium",
        "color": "blond",
        "alcoholPercent": 4.5,
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

my Comment Schema class

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema } = mongoose;

const commentSchema = new Schema({

    _beer:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'beers'},
    postedTime:{type:Date, default:Date.now()},
    comment:String,
    _user:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'} 

});

mongoose.model('comments', commentSchema);
```

query to populate:

```
const  newComment = new Comment({
        _beer:req.params.id,
        comment:'comm1',
        // _user:req.user.id
    });

    newComment.save(function(err){
        if(err) return handleError(err);


        console.log('new comment  saved');

    });

    Beer.findOne({name:'newName'})
        .populate('comments')
        .exec(function(err, comment){
            if(err) return handleError(err);
            console.log('new Comment is %s', comment._beer);
        });
```

my console.log give me undifned error when I try to log comment._beer out.
Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reference model is incorrect `Comment`... It should be `comments`

```
const beerSchema = new Schema({
    name:String,
    country:String,
    color:String,
    alcoholPercent:Number,
    upvotes:{type:Number,  default:0},
    comments:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'comments'}]
}
```

Comment: hmm it didn't fix it. When I leave the type definition behind. I do get the comments back with a get request. But with {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'comments'} I receive an empty 1 back

Comment: @Dave_888 Show the query from which you are getting the data.

Comment: @Dave_888 so what is your issue now?

Comment: please update the question with your collections... your queries and your schemas....

Comment: I did not populate before, now I attempted to do it. But it still not working correctly. thanks for help.

Comment: I cannot help until I do not see your whole collection... please put you both the collections and queries with proper formatting

Comment: found the error in my query, thanks for your effort @Ashish